# Warning from XStream, cannot find itemFieldName in XStreamImplicit

Tags: java, warnings, xstream

I'm trying to track down th source of a warning:

```
warning: Cannot find annotation method 'itemFieldName()' in type 'com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit'
```

The relevant code is:

```
@XStreamAlias("things")
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "things")
private List<Thing> things;
```

Looking at the XStream JAR I see:

```
@java.lang.annotation.Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@java.lang.annotation.Target({java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD})
public static @interface XStreamImplicit {

    java.lang.String itemFieldName() default "";
}
```

So I'm not really sure why I'm getting the warning. It does not appear to be causing problems, but I'm getting a bunch of these in my compiler output and I'd like to tidy them up.

Edit: Did some more digging and found this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/when-good-annotations-go-bad look at the comment from "Fabrizio"

> Hmm.... maybe I'm answering too in a
>   hurry and I didn't understand well...
>   but AFAIK when you have compiled a
>   class C1 that is annotated with A, you
>   can put C1 in the compile (and run)
>   classpath for C2 without the need of
>   putting A in C2 classpath.You only get
>   warnings and A is ignored (as it's
>   proper to do: annotations have a
>   meaning only in a certain context, and
>   in C2 context A is meaningless).
>
> I' ve just  double checked, compiling
>   a sample class X against a JAR that
>   contains javax.persistence annotations
>   (but not putting jpa.jar in the
>   compiler classpath):
>
> istral:/tmp> javac -classpath
>   it-tidalwave-catalog.jar X.java
>   it/tidalwave/catalog/persistence/CategoryPB.class(it/tidalwave/catalog/persistence:CategoryPB.class):
>   warning: Cannot find annotation method
>   'name()' in type
>   'javax.persistence.Table': class file
>   for javax.persistence.Table not found
>   it/tidalwave/catalog/persistence/CategoryPB.class(it/tidalwave/catalog/persistence:CategoryPB.class):
>   warning: Cannot find annotation method
>   'length()' in type
>   'javax.persistence.Column': class file
>   for javax.persistence.Column not found
>   it/tidalwave/catalog/persistence/CategoryPB.class(it/tidalwave/catalog/persistence:CategoryPB.class):
>   warning: Cannot find annotation method
>   'name()' in type
>   'javax.persistence.Column'
>
> etc... Just warnings, the compilation
>   is successful.

So I think, this is just an annotation/classpath issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with XStream - looks pretty nifty - but based on the nature of the annotations you are using (and the [annotations tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html)), I think you have one too many annotations on your `things`. From my quick once-over, the alias annotation converts fully-qualified object names into more appropriate XML element names (the object names are the default). The implicit collections will work without any field name, just using the class name of the collection content type. If you want the collection elements in XML to have a different name, that's when you use the `itemFieldName` property.

My recommendation is to try the same code with just removing the `@XStreamAlias` annotation from `things`, and see if that fixes it. Also, if it works, I think you might want to change the value in `itemFieldName`, because as it stands, you'll have a collection of elements nameed `things` - I think using `thing` instead might work better.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see where you're going. You are correct, using both annotations is unnecessary. http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html I wrote a test and proved it too. Didn't change the compiler warnings though.